# websocket disconnect just after opening handshake

Tags: websocket

I would like to keep the websocket connection alive.
I am using RFC 6455 protocol as websocket protocol.
I tested this via Firefox 13 and Chrome 20.

===WEB SOCKET CLIENT===

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: #.#.#.#:#
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ko-kr,ko;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://its.secret.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: TbJqTlFtGocvRvk/9stMhg==
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

===WEB SOCKET SERVER===

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: outIACgIETcILj0NjzA0MhwP7uc=
```

the newline in this websocket protocol is CR/LF.

the next is the part of websocket client source.

```
var host = "ws://#.#.#.#:#";
try {
    Rsocket = new WebSocket(host);
    Rsocket.onopen = function(msg) {
        alert("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);
    };
    Rsocket.onmessage = function(msg) {...
    };
    Rsocket.onclose = function(msg) {
        alert("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
    };
}
catch (ex) {
    log(ex);
}​
```

First, the success alert appears in the web browser.
Just after pressing OK, the disconnect alert appears.

Although pressing OK when the success alert appears, I would like the disconnect alert not to appear.

Comment: Is your server closing its socket after completing the handshake?  You need to keep the connection open for the duration of the session.

Comment: What software are you using on the server side?